Create Drag Image offset in Jetpack Compose
Is there anywhere in the .dragAndDropSource { ..// } I can offset the dragCoordinates to be above where the user presses on the screen? I'd like for them to be able to see the row that they are dropping the data into, as there is text which helps with UX.
Row(
    modifier = modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .dragAndDropSource {
            detectTapGestures(
                onLongPress = {
                    transferHudViewModel.startDragging()
                    startTransfer(
                        DragAndDropTransferData(
                            ClipData(
                                "AccountOverview",
                                arrayOf("MimTypes stuff"),
                                ClipData.Item("N/A")
                            ),
                            localState = dragAndDropPayload,
                        ),
                    )
                },
            )
        }
) {
    // content
}


Yes, you can offset the drag coordinates in the dragAndDropSource composable by adjusting the position where the drag starts. This can be achieved by modifying the coordinates when starting the drag.
Here is an example of how to achieve this by using the offset function to move the drag start position above where the user presses:
import androidx.compose.foundation.gestures.detectTapGestures
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.*
import androidx.compose.runtime.*
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.pointerInput
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp

@Composable
fun DraggableRow(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    transferHudViewModel: TransferHudViewModel,
    dragAndDropPayload: Any
) { 
           
    val dragOffset = Offset(0f, -50.dp.toPx())  // Offset to move the drag    position 50dp above the touch point

    Row(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .dragAndDropSource {  // Add the dragAndDropSource to the Modifier
                detectTapGestures(
                    onLongPress = {
                        transferHudViewModel.startDragging()
                        startTransfer(
                            DragAndDropTransferData(
                                ClipData(
                                    "AccountOverview",
                                    arrayOf("MimTypes stuff"),
                                    ClipData.Item("N/A")
                                ),
                                localState = dragAndDropPayload,
                                // Apply the offset here
                                position = it + dragOffset  // it represents the position where the user long-pressed
                            ),
                        )
                    },
                )
            }
    ) {
        // content
    }
}



Aiii wallah! Thank you my friend.

unfortunately this doesn't work. No parameter for position.
